# Is Android's BaseAdapter an example of Adapter pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, adapter, baseadapter

Does Android's class BaseAdapter have "Adapter" in its name because it follows the Adapter pattern or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 21):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

> In computer programming, the adapter pattern (often referred to as the
>   wrapper pattern or simply a wrapper) is a design pattern that
>   translates one interface for a class into a compatible interface.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)
>   An adapter allows classes to work together that normally could not
>   because of incompatible interfaces, by providing its interface to
>   clients while using the original interface.

So, let's discect that. BaseAdapters specify an interface to use for programs that need adapters. In fact, this interface is called Adapter. This interface specifies the information needed to take an arbitrary list, and convert it to an arbitrarily long set of Views. BaseAdapter thus adapts your custom input format (In particularly, if you extend it), to the Adapter interface. Thus, it is an Adapter design pattern.