# Show items in ListView filtered by Date

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a ListView in my application. It holds information belonging to an object. The most important value in the Object is a date value. I need to make sort the ListView items by date like so...

```
12-12-2018
13-12-2018
14-12-2018
15-12-2018
```

I can't assume the dates will come like that from the Web Service and they could bring back later ones before the upcoming ones.

I sorted the objects first and passed them into the adapter but felt that might be cumbersome and thought maybe the ListView might do this for me. Is there a better way of doing this or is this the best way? Will the adapter always render the items over each iteration of the list of objects?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android  OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814176/how-to-format-date-and-time-in-xaml-in-xamarin-application

Comment: Hey ADM Sorry could not think of the word sort and ended up thinking of Format :(. But I am trying to sort by date and was thinking is it best to sort the list first and send to the adapter or is there a way the ListView can do so?

Comment: Just looking for what people would normally do for best standards.

Comment: Use for date a long `Timestamp` is used so list can be sorted easily with long. Whats your case ?

Comment: why dont you order the list of your object by applying an orderby clause on the date?(considering your dates are in DateTime format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [article](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html):

> ListView is an adapter view that does not know the details, such as type and contents, of the views it contains.

From Android design pattern, `ListView` uses [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to display its content. And there is a case talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495405/is-androids-baseadapter-an-example-of-adapter-pattern).

Also, there is another sound, `ListView` is [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Whether Adapter Pattern or MVC, `ListView` doesn't hold the data by itself, it needs a Model to manage the data, and display it by `Adapter`.

---

> Is there a better way of doing this or is this the best way?

Sort the data firstly and pass it to Adapter is the best way. `ListView` can't do it, it is only responsible for displaying the `View`. And in this way, your `ListView` will become more easier to maintain and expand, that means if you want change something on your data, you don't need to change anything on your `ListView`, you just need focus on your `Model` which hold your data.

Comment: Thank you! Those links are really helpful and I learned a good bit! Sorting first makes sense and then pass to the adapter. Thanks again :)